# how can I get an EditText's text of my adapter in grid view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity with GridView and below it is Button, and  have user input - row and col of that grid view. And Adapter of that gridView inflates a layout which contains an Edit text.
My problem is how can I get the text of each gridView while I press my Button in my Activity. Please help me.

```
final int col = variable + 3;
        int row = constraint + 2;
        final int count = col * row;

        gridView = findViewById(R.id.table_calculate);
        gridView.setNumColumns(col);
        final GridTableAdapter adapter = new GridTableAdapter(this, count, condition, col, row);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


        findViewById(R.id.simplex_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText editText = (EditText) adapter.getItem(count);

//                ArrayList<String> arrayList = adapter.getAllData();
//                Intent intent = new Intent(calculatesimplex.this,SimplexResultActivity.class);

                Toast.makeText(calculatesimplex.this, "click lite p" + editText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop items of gridview, you could do like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<gridView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    EditText child = (EditText)gridView.getChildAt(i);
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you , you save my times.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can do something like whenever a user enters some text in edittext you can save that text in sharedPreference.

Like this:

Let's assume you have 4 edittexts.

Now all edittexts have a `id` and a `position` if they are in a `GridView`.

Save the edit texts as

key -  `R.id.edittext+position`  value `edittext.getText().toString()`

Now once `onClick()` is called please get all values by

```
sharedPref.get(R.id.edittext+position)

position can be 0,1,2,3.
```

Hope you get the drift.

Comment: Thank @Abhishek Dubey ,but I dont just want to save them.